# A common term for Promote/Demote?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, business-language

I have been working on a software where there is a section to promote and/or demote other users. 
For last two days, I have been thinking and searching for a common term to group both of these terms together but it seems like I am out of luck or I am searching in the wrong direction.

I was wondering if anyone is aware of a proper term or word which can convey the meaning of promotion/demotion or level change on itself without requiring any further explanation to the user?

**Update**

To make it clear, it's promotion/demotion just like done in school. So Level, Rank etc are out of question. 
Also the term will be better suited if it's a verb for Promotion/Demotion.

Comment: Please, please, please: software, no a;  or a software program or an application. Thank you. How about:  upvote and downvote? As used around here.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out software mistake (: 
Vote will be wrong term in my case as there is no voting here.

Comment: I don't understand what "promotion/demotion just like done in school" means.  Can you elaborate? I know that telling a student she has finished one grade and  is moving on to the next grade can be called "promoting" her. I've never heard of demotion in an academic setting.

Comment: @jejorda2 Demotion isn't common but it can occur. I.e a student fails and is moved back sometimes. Though it's very rare thing but as a software app, I have to include this functionality and that's where the terminology comes.

Comment: Also, sometimes a teacher may promote a student by mistake, so he/she may need to demote them back. I can go with Synonyms/alternative terms if they sound better than promote/demote

Comment: "to promote and/or demote other users", that is what upvoting and downvoting mean on this site

Comment: @Lambie I specifically mentioned that in my case it will wrong. Students don't get upvoted to next class. They get promoted.

Comment: You cannot say "a software". You mean "a piece of software" or "a software program". The word *software* is a mass noun in English, not a count noun. You can therefore only use it partitively ("a piece of", "some") or attributively ("software program", "software upgrade").

Answer (score 2):

[**Transition**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transition) (noun):

a : passage from one state, stage, subject, or place to another : CHANGE
b : a movement, development, or evolution from one form, stage, or style to another

The verb form has the same meanings.

For example:

> *I* ***transitioned*** *to a [lower / higher] grade.*
>   *I am evaluating which users I should **transition** into a different role.*

Comment: I think it's the closest it can get to,  Though the meaning isn't obvious to user on first look but hope to get it implemented it somehow

Answer (score 1):

I might consider something like "User ranking" or "Manage user ranking" or simply "Manage users".

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for a short term else "Promote/Demote" is better than a short phrase.

Comment: How about "Rank"?